# How to run a Perl Dancer Test

Tags: perl, testing, dancer

Reading through the Dancer::Test documentation made it seem straightforward to do a test, but I'm missing something.  If I have the following Dancer application (`WebApp.pm`):

```
package WebApp;
use Dancer;

# declare routes/actions
get '/' => sub {
    "Hello World";
};

dance;
```

and then the following testing file `001_base.t`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 1;

use WebApp;
use Dancer::Test;

response_status_is [GET => '/'], 200, "GET / is found";
```

Then when I run the test: `perl 001_base.t`, the output is that the dancer script starts up:

```
Dancer 1.3132 server 7679 listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
== Entering the development dance floor ...
```

But then waits.  (This is the same as if I just run the code in WebApp.pm).  What am I missing here?  I guess I'm not running the test correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `dancer()` from the WebApp.pm. Here is the correct content:

```
package WebApp;
use Dancer;

# declare routes/actions
get '/' => sub {
    "Hello World";
};

1;
```

Then you test will pass.

The common way to create dancer apps is to declare all the routes in one or more .pm files and to have a file usually called `app.psgi` with the content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Dancer;
use WebApp;
dance;
```

Then to start your web application you should run `perl -Ilib app.psgi`.

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks.  I was also trying to get it working under a different port (than the default 3000) and if I used `set port => 3003;` in WebApp.pm and `Dancer::set port => '3003';` in the testing file, it continued to work.